# Can QUIC prevent DNS/NTP amplification for DDOS

Tags: transport-protocol, ddos

According to Cloudflare's [article](https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-road-to-quic/) dedicated to QUIC - subtitle `Deflecting Reflection` implies that QUIC may prevent tampering IP packets. Doest it meat that QUIC may kill DNS/NTP amplification for DDOS attacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QUIC cannot have any impact on other protocols that use UDP (and are susceptible to DDoS abuse). The linked article states that QUIC is not susceptible to being abused for DDoS, *unlike* other UDP-based protocols.